# I am trying to get the Google Javascript APIv3 to display a map

Tags: embed

I can't get the API to work. I get a message keyword error or you are not authorised to use this application.

Answer (score 0):

Is not necessary auth.

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be good to see what code you are using. I assume you have registered to use the API? and that you are passing your unique Key if required. Can we see the embedded code and maybe we can help you a little bit more.